# How to use Google Analytics or google API to access user location and store into database

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track my site visitors and i think google analytics is fulfill my requirement but i want to access complete google analytics from my server how's this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the API here

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html and http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html